# Where can I find some good documentation about the 'acts_as_list' gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, list

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1 and I would like to have an ordered list for my objects related to an `has_many` \ `belongs_to` association. To do that I am planning to use the [`acts_as_list`](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) gem (*BTW*: is it a good gem to make what I would like to do? or, are there other\better gems?) but I have not found good documentation about that.

*Where I can find some good documentation (eg: tutorials, guides, ...) about the `acts_as_list` gem?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case the RDOC seems to be the best source of docs: http://rubydoc.info/gems/acts_as_list/frames

Generally the source code is pretty readable so you can look directly at that as well: https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list

Here are some other options for what you want to do if you want to compare: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Sortables

I've used acts_as_list and sortable, both are very good.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to sound like a jerk but the [source code](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list/blob/master/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb) is actually the best doc for this little gem.